# Rails engine routes not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application my_app, and an engine my_engine.

my_app routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/api"
end
```

my_engine routes:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  post "files/sync" => "files#sync"
end
```

From my_app, I run `rails routes`, and see the following:

```
              Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
my_engine_engine      /api        MyEngine::Engine

Routes for MyEngine::Engine:
```

As you can see, `Routes for MyEngine::Engine:` displays 0 results. I've tried every answer in the books about this issue, but nothing works.

Why are my engine routes not being listed by the app?

(Note that my_engine is a local gem — do I have to do something special to reload it possibly?)

Answer (score 1):

One solution turned out to be changing:

```
gem 'my_engine', path: '/Users/me/Desktop/my_engine_gem'
```

to:

```
gem 'my_engine', path: '/Users/me/Desktop/my_engine_gem', require: 'my_engine'
```

This worked, even though placing `require 'my_engine'` in an initializer did not work. Not sure what the distinction is.